# Two Users, Same GA Account, Different Time Zones, Same data?

Tags: google-analytics

Here's a riddle (serious question actually): if two users are on GA at the same time but are located in two different timezones, do they see the same data?

I ask because an associate and I are observing a dip in traffic but at wildly different rates: I see -17% on my side but he sees -45%. I'm currently in Pacific Standard Time and he is in Australian Eastern Daylight Time.

Any insights?

Answer (score 1):

You can view or set up a timezone in Google Analytics View.

[image]

By default, Google Analytics will work with this timezone set. However, you can adjust the time zone per view, which could come in handy for sites that operate in a different timezone than you.